# Error when adding NORMAL to the inputLayout

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11, hlsl

I'm trying to add the NORMAL vector into the inputLayout but when I add this line, I have this error :

> D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11Device::CreateInputLayout: The provided input signature expects to read an element with SemanticName/Index: 'NORMAL'/0, but the declaration doesn't provide a matching name. [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #163: CREATEINPUTLAYOUT_MISSINGELEMENT]

Here is where I set up the InputLayout :

```
 {"POSITION",0,DXGI_FORMAT::DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT,0,0,D3D11_INPUT_CLASSIFICATION::D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA,0},
    {"NORMAL",0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT,0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
    {"TEXCOORD", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
```

And here is the VertexShader :

```
struct VSinput
{
float3 pos : POSITION;
float2 textCoord : TEXCOORD0;
float3 test : NORMAL0;
};

struct PSinput
{
float4 position : SV_Position;
float2 textCoord : TEXCOORD0;
float3 test : NORMAL0;
 };

 PSinput vs_main(VSinput input)
 {
  PSinput output = (PSinput) 0;

 // input.pos.y += Yoffset;
  output.position = mul(float4(input.pos, 1.0),mat);

  output.textCoord = input.textCoord;



  return output;


}
```

as you can see there is an input with the NORMAL SemanticName and the Index 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You cannot change the layout order in Direct3D 10 or later due to shader linkage rules.**

Either make your shader use:

```
struct VSinput
{
float3 pos : POSITION;
float3 test : NORMAL0;
float2 textCoord : TEXCOORD0;
};
```

-or- make your input layout use:

```
{"POSITION",0,DXGI_FORMAT::DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT,0,0,D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA,0},
{"TEXCOORD", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
{"NORMAL",0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT,0, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
```